# Access AIC for Generalized Additive Mixed Models (GAMM) generated by r package `gamm4`

Tags: r, gam

I am using the r pacakge `gamm4` to run a gamm on a binary response varible with eight predictor variabels, two of which are smoothed using a thin plate spline. This model runs fine and I can varify it has generated results from `summery()`

Here is a subset of my data:
`structure(list(DATE = c("1/1/1990", "1/2/1990", "1/3/1990",    "1/4/1990", "1/5/1990", "1/6/1990"),`
`RESPONSE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),`
`PREDICTOR1 = c(100L, 80L, 60L, 100L, 100L, 100L),` 
`PREDICTOR2 = c(5.3, 3.8, 2.5, 2.2, 2.8, 4),` 
`PREDICTOR3 = c(0.001016002, 0, 0, 0.001778004, 0.021590043, 0),` `PREDICTOR4 = c(315, 90, 90, 315, 360, 225),` 
`PREDICTOR5 = c(1019.326087, 1028.770833, 1027.920833, 1024.4625, 1022.25, 1018.891667),` 
`PREDICTOR6 = c(17.36086957, 12.1, 13.02083333, 16.5375, 16.48333333, 19.6375),` 
`PREDICTOR7 = c(13.47916667, 12.775, 12.525, 12.3875, 12.725, 13.09166667),` 
`PREDICTOR8 = c(0.28335247, 0.212789468, 0.239630838, 0.386550722, 0.221811468, 0.379079404),`
`random_effect1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),`

Here is my model formula:

```
model_1 <- gamm(RESPONSE ~ PREDICTOR1 + PREDICTOR2 + PREDICTOR3 + s(PREDICTOR4) + 
           PREDICTOR5 + s(PREDICTOR6) + PREDICTOR7 + PREDICTOR8, data = data, 
           random = random_effect1, family = binomial())
```

However, when I attempt to run AIC on the gamm outcome object it fails

```
aic_model1 <- AIC(model_1)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") :
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class
 "c('gamm', 'list')"
```

I have attemted to break down the AIC parts and calculate the fitted values using `predict.gam` and

```
deviance_model <- 
  -2 * sum(log(dbinom(model_1$RESPONSE, size = 1, prob = fitted_values)))
```

Both of these generate a `NULL` result.
I also attempted `AIC.gam` and `AIC.gamm` those these failed.
The issue (though I could be mistaken) appears to be the class of the object `gamm, list`. Does anyone know how to get around this issue? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you add to your OP part of your data?

Comment: I've added a link to the first month of my data in a google doc

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a sample of the data using `dput()` instead of a link to a Google doc?

Comment: Done, though I only included a small chunk using `dput(head(data))`. My data has over 10k rows. Let me know if more is necessary. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are *not* using `gamm4()` in your code. The package *gamm4* provides a function with name `gamm4()`, not `gamm()`.

If you're willing to use the AIC from the mixed model formulation (read `?mgcv::logLik.gam`, what I show below yields the *marginal* likelihood-based AIC, which integrates out the random effects and hence the [wiggly bits of the] smooths) then you can apply the `AIC()` function to the `$mer` component of the object returned by `gamm4()`

```
# use example from ?gamm4::gamm4
set.seed(0) 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2) ## simulate 4 term additive truth

## Now add 20 level random effect `fac'...
dat$fac <- fac <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))
dat$y <- dat$y + model.matrix(~fac-1)%*%rnorm(20)*.5
br <- gamm4(y~s(x0)+x1+s(x2),data=dat,random=~(1|fac))
```

Now apply `AIC()` to `br$mer` such that the `logLik()` method for the mixed model class (`"merMod"`) is used:

```
> AIC(br$mer)                                                                
[1] 1811.787
```

You can't do this with `gamm()` models with non_Gaussian families as those models are actually fitted via `MASS::glmmPQL()` and that functions does't maximise a likelihood (it uses a penalized quasilikelihood) and as such there is no likelihood and no AIC.

The point about the returned object containing multiple model fits remains; these functions return the mixed model form as one component and a GAM form as the second component. Use `str(my_model, max = 1)` to see the names of these two components as they differ between model fitting functions.

Comment: I started to answer something like this but got worried when I could make results match between `logLik(gamm4_fit$mer)` and `logLik(mgcv_fit)` ...